# Why can I not convert my JSON encoded data in my swift project

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to convert JSON with my custom structs using the codable protocol but I get the error message `The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.`

Here is my network call method;

```
    func fetchSocketData(symbols: [String], completion: @escaping ([StockInfo])->()) {
        
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        lazy var webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: FINNHUB_SOCKET_API_URL!)
        
        var stock = [StockInfo]()
        
        for symbol in symbols {
            
            let string = "{\"type\":\"subscribe\",\"symbol\":\"\(symbol)\"}"
            
            let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(string)
            
            webSocketTask.send(message) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error sending message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                webSocketTask.receive { result in

                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Error receiving message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        
                    case .success(.string(let jsonData)):
                        print(jsonData)
                        guard let stockData = jsonData.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        do {
                            let data = try decoder.decode(SocketData.self, from: stockData)
                            print(data)
                        } catch {
                            print("Error converting JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                        
                    default:
                        print("default")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//        completion(stock)
        webSocketTask.resume()
    }
}
```

and here is my model code;

```
struct SocketData: Codable {
    var data: [StockInfo]
    var type: String
}

struct StockInfo: Codable {
    var tradeConditions: [String]
    var price: Double
    var symbol: String
    var timestamp: Double
    var volume: Double
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case symbol = "s"
    case price = "p"
    case timestamp = "t"
    case volume = "v"
    case tradeConditions = "c"
    case data
    case type
}
```

Here is some sample JSON;

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "c": ["1", "12"],
         "p": 164.18,
         "s": "AAPL",
         "t": 1646157925188,
         "v": 1
      },
      {
         "c": ["1", "12"],
         "p": 164.18,
         "s": "AAPL",
         "t": 1646157925188,
         "v": 1
      }
   ],
   "type":"trade"
}
```

I feel I have tried everything to get this to work but to no avail. I am sure I have written the custom structs correctly.

Comment: Replace `print("Error converting JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")` with `print("Error converting JSON: \(error)")` to get the **real** error. Hint: The CodingKeys must be **inside** the structs respectively. It's even recommended to declare them as `private enum`. And – however it doesn't cause errors – there are some `Int` values rather than `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Error converting JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
```

=>

```
print("Error converting JSON: \(error)")
```

It will give you more useful information, like:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "tradeConditions", intValue: nil), 
                       Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil),
                                                               _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], 
                                                   debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"tradeConditions\", intValue: nil) (\"tradeConditions\").", 
                                                   underlyingError: nil))
```

In other words, it's saying that's it's not finding a value for the key `tradeConditions` in you JSON.

What's wrong in fact:

Let's see the [doc of Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types), especially the part "Choose Properties to Encode and Decode Using Coding Keys":

> Codable types can declare a special **nested** enumeration named CodingKeys that conforms to the CodingKey protocol.

I put in bold the important part.

In other words, you have currently:

```
struct StructA: Codable {}
struct structB: Codable {}

enum CodingKeysForSructAAndStructB: String, CodingKey {}
```

Okay, so, now let's imagine this:

```
struct StructA: Codable {
    let propertyA: String
}
struct StructB: Codable {
    let propertyA: Int
}
```

How could you have two properties with the same name in different struct, but with different coding keys?

```
enum CodingKeysForSructAAndStructB: String, CodingKey {
    case propertyA = "something"     //For StructA
    case propertyA = "somethingElse" //For StructB
}
//That's invalid, and that wouldn't make really sense that you need to rename one of the properties...
```

So you need to nest them, to let the compiler know which one use which key:

```
struct SocketData: Codable {
    var data: [StockInfo]
    var type: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
        case type
    }
}

struct StockInfo: Codable {
    var tradeConditions: [String]
    var price: Double
    var symbol: String
    var timestamp: Double
    var volume: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case symbol = "s"
        case price = "p"
        case timestamp = "t"
        case volume = "v"
        case tradeConditions = "c"
    }
}
```